# move all duplicate values in a list to the right of the list and unique values to the left

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the below input list and I want the output list with time complexity O(n) and space complexity O(1). I am able to solve it using more space complexity but ideally it should be O(1).

input = [1,2,1,3,3,1,2,4]
out   = [1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3]

Comment: Why do you want those complexities? Did someone tell you that that's the goal? If so, then I think something is wrong, as that seems impossible.

Comment: Could you restate the question within the question's body? Right now your actual question is only in the title.

Comment: To filter duplicates, you need backtracking. There's no way, or at least not that I've heard of, to backtrack without consuming either time or space.

Comment: @InSync It might be kinda possible if the numbers range from 1 to n. But that would need to be stated.

Answer (score 0):

Do I need to sort it?

An idea

But insert time complexity is O(n)

Not satisfied time complexity O(n)

```py
input = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4]
out = []
i = 0
for num in input:
    if num in out:
        out.append(num)
    else:
        out.insert(i, num)
        i += 1

print(out)
```